# JSF Pagination(Prime Faces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 17000 data.and my rows per page is 20.So ideally it should display 850 pages.But to my surprise its only showing 500 pages .
Please help.
My code snippet is like this:-

```
  <p:dataTable var="offer" value="#{viewReviseOffersCtrl.lazyModel}"  
            id="offerDetail" paginator="true" rows="#{msg['max.rows']}" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}   
  {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            rendered="#{not empty 
  viewReviseOffersCtrl.lstDisplayOffers}"
            resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" width="100%"  
  scrollHeight="265"
            sortBy="#{offer.createdTs}" 
            lazy="true">
```

Comment: Maybe 500 is the max it can show. Check the documentation

Comment: the list doesn't get increase when you reach 500 ?